# Clone/duplicate internal modules in the admin (sales, orders...) in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

i need to clone the "orders" module which is available under `sales->orders`. I have made a copy of the `sales/order.php` under the controller, model and languages to `sales/your_orders.php` and changed the class names and language files to the relevant name.

But i cant see Your Orders below the sales menu in the administration.

Can someone please let me know how can i get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Now You have to edit also the controller, language file and template for `header`

- `admin/controller/common/header.php`
- `admin/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/common/header.php`
- `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`

and add (copy and edit) lines for that new menu entry...

Answer (score 0):

- Duplicate and edit text, var

`//files
admin/controller/common/header.php 
admin/language/english/common/header.php 
admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`

- Duplicate & edit database table
- Set Permission

Or using

```
vqmod
```